# Example of a non-surjective isometric mapping on a totally bounded metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, isometry

This question originates from this terrific [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36511) by Qiaochu Yuan. For convenience, I copy it here.

> **Proposition:** Any isometry[isometric mapping] $f : X \to X$ of a compact metric space is bijective.
>
> *Proof.* $f$ is clearly injective. Suppose $f$ is not bijective. Then $f(X)$ is compact, so given $x \in X \setminus f(X)$ the distance
>   $\text{dist}(x, f(X))$ is positive. Pick $\epsilon < \text{dist}(x,
> > f(X))$. Let $N$ be the smallest positive integer for which $X$ admits
>   a cover by $N$ open sets of diameter less than $\epsilon$. No such set
>   containing $x$ can intersect $f(X)$, but by pulling back along $f$ it
>   follows that we can find a cover of $X$ by $N-1$ open sets of diameter
>   less than $\epsilon$; contradiction.

The answer assumes that there exist $x$ such that $\text{dist}(x, f(X))$ is positive, that is to say, $X\backslash f(X)$ has an non-empty interior. This assumption is true due to the fact that $X$ is compact and thus complete.

However, the rest of the proof does not rely on the fact that $X$ is compact. It's true that compactness implies the existence of a cover by $N<\infty$ open sets of diameter less than $\epsilon$, but the latter does not imply compactness. To ensure the existence of such a cover, we just need $X$ to be totally bounded, i.e. $\forall \epsilon,\exists a_1,\ldots,a_n\in X, X\subseteq \cup_{i=1}^nB(a_i,\epsilon)$.

So can anyone give a (counter)example, showing that if $X$ is not compact but is totally bounded, then $f$ can FAIL to be surjective?

Comment: @YuiToCheng Then $B$ would be compact (complete + totally bounded)  which is not true.

Comment: @HoldingArthur The unit ball in $\ell^2$ is closed, hence complete. It cannot be totally bounded. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109550 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/287360.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes I know that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [example of not surjective isometry on a bounded not closed set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233277/example-of-not-surjective-isometry-on-a-bounded-not-closed-set) (A subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ is bounded iff it is totally bounded)